# Why this query doesn't works

Tags: php, joomla, joomla2.5

I am not confirmed with this query... I feel like somewhere the CU or CI has been misplaced...
This query worked properly without using $db->nameQuote in sql.

```
 $query = 'SELECT '. $db->nameQuote(CU.'id')
        .' FROM '. $db->nameQuote('#__users'), $db->nameQuote('#__community_cinvit' CI)
        .' WHERE '. $db->nameQuote(CU.'email').'='.$db->Quote(CI.'to_email')
        .'AND'. $db->nameQuote(CI.'point_given').'='.$db->Quote('1');

        $db->setQuery($query);
        $conn = $db->loadResult();
        echo $conn;
```

is there any error in CU and CI

Comment: Maybe you can post here echo of $query?

Comment: ya added..  $db->nameQuote('#__community_cinvit' CI) is this correct  SELECT CU.id
FROM jom_community_users CU,jom_community_invit CI
WHERE CU.email = CI.to_email
AND CI.point_given = 1   this is the query that worked on sql

Comment: use this : mail('email@site.be', __FILE__ . ' => ' . __LINE__, $query);
to mail te query to yourself and execute it in phpmyadmin to see what's wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add white space before `.' AND'.` and add `CU` to `$db->nameQuote('#__users' CU)`

```
 $query = 'SELECT '. $db->nameQuote(CU.'id')
        .' FROM '. $db->nameQuote('#__users' CU), $db->nameQuote('#__community_cinvit' CI)
        .' WHERE '. $db->nameQuote(CU.'email').'='.$db->Quote(CI.'to_email')
        .' AND'. $db->nameQuote(CI.'point_given').'='.$db->Quote('1');

        $db->setQuery($query);
        $conn = $db->loadResult();
        echo $conn;
```